# How to add level number or ID to a parameter in Facebook analytics "Breakdown"

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, analytics

I've attached an image([Click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNgs1.png)) that shows(vertically) IDs for levels.
I need IDs for levels to understand how many players played a particular level in my Game through Facebook analytics "Breakdowns".
How to get these IDs as shown in the image?
For me it's just showing "All Others".. there is a topics on trouble shoot, here: https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/885102478239387

but it doesn't help. Do we need to write custom events with parameters, or just use "AcheievedLevel" to log level-completion-event (in built event for casual game)?

I tried using it from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/best-practices/gaming-casual/

but it throws error if I just directly copy paste this code.

```
 public void LogAchievedLevelEvent(string level)
 {
     var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     parameters[AppEventParameterName.Level] = level;
     FB.LogAppEvent(AppEventName.AchievedLevel,parameters);
 }
```

Someone please help with this. I'm not an experienced developer, just an artist trying to develop my 2nd  game professionally. Any help will be greatly appreciated and thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: I don't know if your actual code has this, but what you put up above has commented out parts. You have // on the first line so you're commented out the method declaration leaving only what's in the brackets.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your reply. Actually it's not commented out in the game. 

This was my first question I've submitted here and there were some errors which I had to fix before posting, I thought it's because of the error coming from code, so I just commented it here. 

Apologies, if that led to confusion. I've edited the post so that it doesn't create any more confusion.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>' to 'float?'

direct copy paste shows the error above...also is this how we usually track level progression?

I've also tried this method below-

   public void LogCompletedEvent(string levelName, double levelNumber)
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["LevelName"] = levelName;
        FB.LogAppEvent("LevelCompleted", (float)levelNumber, parameters);
    }

And there's no error, but not seeing the levelName strings in Facebook analytics breakdown